# Configuración del PATH de ejecución con Process en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Windows Forms que lanza múltiples aplicaciones externas; estas a su vez, generan archivos de texto que son leídos por la aplicación principal.

El problema es que las aplicaciones externas creen que están ejecutándose en el directorio de la aplicación principal y cuando buscan sus dependencias *(sus dlls)* y/o generan documentos lo buscan en ésta dirección, dándome error.

Algo asi como:

> `\bin\Debug\TEXTO.txt`

Cuando debería escribirse en:

> `\bin\Debug\APP_EXTERNA\TEXTO.txt`

o el fallo de la DLL que la busca:

> en: `\bin\Debug\app_externa.dll`

En vez de buscarla en esta ruta:

> ejecutable `\bin\Debug\APP_EXTERNA\app_externa.dll`

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la aplicación externa se ejecute en su dirección y no en el path principal?

Seguro que existe algo similar a las variables de entorno, pero lo desconozco en C#.

Este es el código:

```
private string processModules(bool start, string dir, string args)
{
    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "APP_EXTERNA\\app_externa.exe", //  con el mismo resultado --> Application.StartupPath,
            Arguments = args,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        }
    };
        process.Start();
        outputs = File.ReadLines(@"TEXTO.txt").Last();
        Console.WriteLine(outputs);
        process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Para obtener variables de entorno string varEntorno = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

Comment: Gracias Alejandro, quizás no me expresé bien, me refería al Directorio de Trabajo (pero desconocía dicho nombre)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configura la propiedad **ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory** con el path que deseas que la app externa use como base.

Comment: Fenomeno!! El único detalle es que he tenido que cambiar el formato de la declaracion (desconozco el motivo) con éxito a: `var process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "APP_EXTERNA\\";
    process.StartInfo.FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "APP_EXTERNA\\app_externa.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;`

Comment: Un detalle aprovechando vuestro conocimiento: En qué se diferencia la **@**"APP_EXTERNA\\app_externa.exe" y "APP_EXTERNA\\app_externa.exe"?

Comment: Cuando usas "" las "secuencias de escape" como \r \n \t \\ se convierten en "retorno", "brinco del linea", "tabulacion" y "\"--- Cuando usas @"" se quedan como caracteres \r \n \t y \\